# How to support tab button by resource id instead of text on Firebase Robo Test

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am using Firebase Robo script test now.
I found out the robo script would failed because robo script recorded the 
 text of button I clicked instead of the resource id.
When I want to i18n test, it would failed in other language.
Anyway to prevent this ?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in more detail about what you mean by "robo script recorded the text of button I clicked instead of the resource id". I am under the impression that Robo should detect and use view IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the recorded Robo script will contain `ids`, `text` and `contentDescriptions` of elements. When this script gets used all specified fields need to match. There are 2 ways around this:

a) Manually remove the `elementDescriptors` fields from the script that you don't want to be used for matching.

b) There's an option in Android Studio that allows you to disable the recording of `text` and `contentDescription` fields. Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Espresso Test Recorder and uncheck both "Use text for element matching" and "Use content description for element matching". Afterwards re-record the Robo script. It should no longer contain `text` and `contentDescription` fields in the `elementDescriptors` array.